# It's all Greek to me

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

*Something* doesn't just add up.

And *this is barely a puzzle*.

How can *everything* be so important?

Maybe there's an **alternate** way to find the answer to what this OP is craving?

HINT:

> The sum of the parts is equal to the whole.

HINT 2:

> Something does actually add up. But if at first you don't succeed, try again.

HINT 3:

> There happens to be an entirely different and unrelated answer from what I had in mind that I will accept as well. By happenstance I stumbled upon it and it nearly fits perfectly.

Comment: I added a hint above. If you want another let me know.

Comment: I sure do!!! 

Comment: I just added another hint today. This one is a bit more important than the first. This puzzle does not have an obvious solution at first; however you will know when you come to the correct answer based on the puzzle itself.

Comment: This wouldn't happen to involve greek numerals now would it...?

Comment: This was my first puzzle written so it's a bit of a clumsy one, I'm afraid. The words used were very specific, but it may need another hint for people to get onto the right track.

Comment: Is the answer CDII? Or maybe CD 2?

Answer (score 12):

I think the answer is

> SETS

Considering only the first para is relevant-

> Something doesn't add up **...** Plus this is barely a puzzle **.** How can everything be so important **?** There must be an alternate way to find the answer **...**
>
>  Assuming there is a Morse Code hidden in the para. And, ?=Dash & .=DOT
>
>  we get ... . - ... -> **SETS** So OP is craving for SETS :)

Comment: A good effort, but it's a bit more complicated than that. There are key words in the riddle that are used to derive the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have hard evidence, but I think the OP is craving

> Pie

Reasoning below, admittedly, this is essentially guesswork.

> The terms "Add up" and "Plus" point to something mathematical.
>  The question asks about a craving, indicating food.
>  Considering the title, "It's all Greek to me", we're looking for something Greek, mathematical and alimentary.
>  Therefore, Pi, as a Greek letter, a mathematical constant, and phonetically, a dish, fits pretty well.

Comment: The words "plus" and "add up" are big hints; however, I may have made this riddle too ambiguous. It was one of my first. If you want another hint let me know.

Comment: I think this is the right track, considering (cv vf gur inyhr bs fbzr snzbhf nygreangvat vasvavgr fhzf!)

Answer (score 5):

All the clues seem to point towards it being:

> Sigma (a greek letter)

For the reasons that

> The symbol $\Sigma$ is used for summation in mathematics, also from hint number two "If you first don't succeed" seems to be talking about error, the lower case sigma $\sigma$ is usually used to denote errors.

However I'm not sure what this ties into as far as something the OP desires unless:

> They want to be 18 (sigma is the 18th letter of the greek alphabet or [make-up brushes](http://www.sigmabeauty.com/).

Comment: Good reasoning. As I stated in a comment above I may have made this a little too ambiguous, being my first riddle. There are important words that should be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Is OP craving

> lamb?

Reasoning:

> Take the number of words in each line and add them up: 5+6+6+6+9+6=38. Add 3 and 8 (suggested by hint 2): 3+8=11. The 11th letter in the Greek alphabet is lambda (lamb).

Comment: So far your idea is the closest to what I had in mind. Not quite, but close.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's:

> PITA

Reasoning:

> **Something doesn't just add up. 
> And this is barely a puzzle.**
>  If I count all the syllables in this sentence I get **15**. Since it doesn't add up I assume one is missing to get **16** or **P**
>  **How can everything be so important?**
>  If I simply count all the syllables in this sentence I get **9** or **I**.
>  **Each line must provide a clue.
> Maybe there's an alternate way to find the answer...**
>  Adding up the syllables in these two lines I find **20** or **T**.
>  **Maybe there's an alternate way to find the answer...**
>  This lead me to count *all the syllables* including 'To what OP is craving...' this is exactly **52**. If I add the one added from the previous 'doesn't add up' I get **53**. If I **mod 26** then I get **1** or **A**.
>  Combined with the title **It's all Greek to me**. I have to assume PITA is what you crave.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's:

> Staggering Elk Lager
> BTW it's a real beer, see:
> http://www.pintley.com/beer/Staggering-Elk-Lager/5027/

Because:

> Hints and text suggest the question didn't need much/any text. Treating the title as a cryptic clue...
> It's **all Greek** to me
> Anagram of "all Greek" is "Elk Lager"
> So a *staggering* "Elk Lager" could be "all Greek"

Comment: The title is certainly important, but this sadly is not the answer I'm looking for.. although I may indeed crave it later.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@Asteria's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48323/its-all-greek-to-me/50303#50303)
Maybe its-

> Η η  eta, ήτα

Explanation

> Counting all the letters from each line and adding them
> **Something doesn't just add up.**
> COUNTS - 9 6 4 3 2
> SUM -24
> FURTHER SUM - 6
> **And this is barely a puzzle.**
> COUNTS - 3 4 2 6 1 6
> SUM -22
> FURTHER SUM - 4
> **How can everything be so important?**
> COUNTS - 3 3 10 2 2 9
> SUM -29
> FURTHER SUM - 11
> *AGAIN FURTHER SUM - 2*
> **Each line must provide a clue.**
> COUNTS - 4 4 4 7 1 4
> SUM -24
> FURTHER SUM - 6
> **Maybe there's an alternate way to find the answer...**
> COUNTS -  5 6 2 9 3 2 4 3 6
> SUM - 40
> FURTHER SUM - 4
> **To what this OP is craving.**
> COUNTS - 2 4 4 2 2 7
> SUM - 21
> FURTHER SUM - 3       
> Adding all the FURTHER SUM 6 + 4 + 11 + 6 + 4 + 3 = 34
> And 3 + 4 = 7    
>
> Alternatively
> Adding all the FURTHER SUM and instead of 11 I added 2(11's digit sum) (for alternative approach) we get 25
> 2 + 5 = 7    
>
>
> By both way we get 7 and hence the 7th Greek alphabet.

Comment: Very close! However, not every word needs to be part of the sum. E.g. "And"

Comment: Great idea on adding sums, definitely on the right track! The puzzle did not count the number of letters, but you're certainly the closest in concept for the solution.

Comment: Something entertaining about this answer is that the 7th letter of the Greek alphabet sounds like "eat a". You have the right idea, but not quite there.